# Disappearing "From" field in Apple Mail

Tags: macos, mail.app

In Apple Mail (7.3) on Mavericks (10.9.4), when I compose a new message, I cannot choose which of my two accounts to send from.  Bizarrely, when I open the New Message window, there is a From field, but it quickly disappears.  I'm including an animated GIF showing this behavior below.  How do I stop the From field from vanishing?

[image: Screen capture of the disappearing From field]

Comment: The resolution of that GIF deserves an upvote just by itself :)

Comment: You have the inbox of one of your accounts selected when you do this? Does this still happen if you select the inbox at the top (so it sees both accounts)?

Comment: @GeorgeGarside, thanks for the up vote! My original video was a higher-res mp4, but I had to make it a GIF to embed it in my question. The free online format converter I used gave me the low-res version you see, which I think has a charming quaintness to it.

Comment: @PaulGilfedder, I forget to mention this. The weirdness happens (or happened, since it's fixed now) when using the unified inbox too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your preferences and go to "composing" amd change the setting for "Send new messages from:", close the preferences, quit mail, and then reset your preference to what you want.

If this doesn't work, make sure you don't have any Mail plugins installed.

Check the folder(s) if they exist:

`$HOME/Library/Mail/V2/Bundles/
 $HOME/Library/Mail/Bundles/`

Comment: Wow, thank you, that worked! Specifically the first part, where I change the "Send new messages from" setting, quit mail, and open it back up. @lbutlr, I'm really curious as to how you figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen that exact behavior before, but have seen some strangeness in the message fields when the outgoing mail servers are not configured cleanly (or have some how gotten bungled).

If the ideas previously presented don't work try going into Preferences --> Accounts --> Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) --> Edit SMTP List. In there, check to make sure you only have entries for each account (assuming you use different outgoing mail servers for each. Check settings for each to make sure each is unique and not in conflict. I also find it easier to have "Use only this server checked" on the account configuration screen.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this: I went to Mail Accounts and selected one of the accounts and under "outgoing mail server" I unchecked the box that said "use only this server". Fixed! (I had 2 accounts, if you have more than 2 maybe you have to uncheck this in more than one account)